# a possible contradiction in the memorylessness property of exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

while studying memorylessness property of the exponential distribution i came across this:

$$\mathbb P(X>s+t)=\mathbb P(X>t)\cdot \mathbb P(X>s+t|X>t)\tag{1}$$

$$\mathbb P(X>t)\cdot \mathbb P(X>s+t\mid X>t)=\mathbb P(X>t)\cdot \mathbb P(X>s)\tag{2}
$$
which implies that $\mathbb P(X>s+t)=\mathbb P(X>s)\cdot \mathbb P(X>t)$.

my problem is that when we let $s=-t$ , then what we get is,

$$1=\mathbb P(X>0)=\mathbb P(X>t-t)=\mathbb P(X>t)\cdot \mathbb P(X>-t)=\mathbb P(X>t)\cdot 1 \neq 1$$

which is a contradiction. Surely i did something wrong but i cant figure out what it is.

edit1:

but if $t>0$ and $s<0$ then $$\mathbb P\{X>s+t\mid X>t\}=\frac{\mathbb P\{X>s+t,X>t\}}{\mathbb P\{X>t\}}\underset{\mathbb P\{X>t\}\neq1}{=}\frac{\mathbb P\{X>t\}}{\mathbb P\{X>t\}}= 1.$$

which implies that (using $(1)$)  $\space \space \mathbb P\{X>s+t\} = \mathbb P\{X>t\}*1$

Comment: Equation 1 is wrong, in general. Total probability theorem has been incorrectly used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is the time until the first occurrence in a Poisson process.

$\{X>t+s\}$ thus represents the event of a Poisson arrival not occurring within the interval $(0,t+s]$.

When $s$ is positive the intervals $(0,t]$ and $(t, t+s]$ are disjoint, and the probability that the event does not arrives within the second interval when given that it does not arrive within the first of equal measure to the probability that it does not arrive within $(0,s]$. $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\notin(0,t]\land X\notin (t,t+s])~&=~\mathsf P(X\notin(0,t])\cdot\mathsf P(X\notin(t,t+s]\mid X\notin (0,t])\\[1ex]\therefore\quad\mathsf P(X\notin(0,t+s])~&=~\mathsf P(X\notin(0,t)]\cdot\mathsf P(X\notin(0,s])\end{align}$$

However, when $s$ is negative the intervals $(0,t]$ and $(t+s, t]$ are clearly intersecting and thus ....

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\notin(0,t]\land X\notin (t+s,t])~&=~\mathsf P(X\notin(0,t])\cdot\mathsf P(X\notin(t+s,t]\mid X\notin (0,t])\\[2ex]\therefore\quad\mathsf P(X\notin(0,t])~&=~\mathsf P(X\notin(0,t])\cdot 1\qquad\text{unsurprisingly}\end{align}$$

Comment: for s<0, event X>t+s is not the same as the event X not in [0,t]. event X>t+s is the same as the event X not in [0,s+t]. hence you have answered a derivative of my question!

Comment: Yes, exactly the point. When $s$ is negative, $(0,t]\cup(t+s, t]\neq(0,t+s]$, so the memoryless argument of splitting the interval into two disjoint subsets does not work.

Answer (score 2):

No contradiction. $$\mathbb P\{X>s+t\}=\mathbb P\{X>t\}\mathbb P\{X>s\},$$
only if $s,t\geq 0$. Indeed, if $t<0$ then $$\mathbb P\{X>t+s\mid X>t\}=\frac{\mathbb P\{X>t+s\}}{\mathbb P\{X>t\}}\underset{\mathbb P\{X>t\}=1}{=}\mathbb P\{X>t+s\}\neq \mathbb P\{X>s\}.$$

Comment: Likewise, if $s\leqslant 0$ then $\{X>t\}\subseteq \{X>t+s\}$ and consequently $$\Bbb P(X>t+s\mid X>t)=1$$